# How to make jQuery slidetoggle effect for multiple div on same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

it works fine for one `div`

```
(function($) { 
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#div1').hide();
        $('a.plus').click(function(){
           $('#div1').slideToggle();
           $(this).toggleClass("minus_icon"); 
           return false;
        });
     });
})(jQuery);
```

How to make this slide toogle effect for multiple `div` on same page? I have multiple `div`s with different id to hide like `#div1`, `#div2`, `div#3`.

edit:

This is situation in html

```
<a class="plus"> more details </a>
<div id="div1" class="description">
<p> Hidden content here </p>
</div>

<a class="plus"> more details </a>
<div id="div2" class="description">
<p> Hidden content here </p>
</div>

<a class="plus"> more details </a>
<div id="div3" class="description">
<p> Hidden content here </p>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "`<a id="plus">` is same in all", I hope you don't meant that you have more than one element with the ID `plus`. Because that is not allowed. IDs must be unique.

Comment: +1 yes you are right. It's my mistake.

Comment: Are you saying that there is a one to one relationship between the `<a>` elements and the `<div>` elements?

Comment: @patrick - no, I changed `a id="plus"` to `a class="plus"`

Comment: Yes, but I mean are you saying that for each `<a>`, there is one `<div>`, or several?

Comment: It is just tough to tell you what you can do without knowing the exact situation (via some HTML markup perhaps). There must be some relationship between each `<a>` and its associated `<div>` elements that we can build on.

Comment: @metal - I thought you said that for each `<a>` there were several `<div>` elements. Your code shows only one `div` per `a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(function($) { 
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#div1, #div2, #div3').hide();
            $('a.plus').click(function(){
               $(this).next().slideToggle();
               $(this).toggleClass("minus_icon"); 
               return false;
            });
         });
    })(jQuery);

Comment: @HiddenChilli - thanks it's working. can we do one more thing. I want to make it dynamic. see i'm using here div like div1 div2 div3. is it possible to have same effect using @div only like `div'+substr($(this).id, 4)`

Comment: for example my id of `div` will always have in same format `div1`, `div2` or `div11`, `div12` . so i want to make this code dynamic then there will be no need to modify jquery file ,when i will add more `div` in `HTML`. will be easier for my client.

Comment: oh i see do you mean $('div.description').hide()?

Comment: try this: $('a.plus').next().hide();

Answer (score 2):

Presuming your HTML is something like this:

```
<div id="div1" class="more">Content</div>
<a class="plus">Show More</a>

<div id="div2" class="more">Content</div>
<a class="plus">Show More</a>

<div id="div3" class="more">Content</div>
<a class="plus">Show More</a>
```

Then having a function like this will work for as many `a.plus` / `div` pairs you have:

```
(function($) { 
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.more').hide();
    $('a.plus').click(function(){
       $(this).prev().slideToggle(); // if your divs are after the plus, use next() instead
       $(this).toggleClass("minus_icon"); 
       return false;
    });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

If your `a.more`s are, for whatever reason, nowhere near the `div`s themselves, you will have to set an attribute on the `a.more` to link it to a div, eg. (HTML)

```
<a class="plus" data-article="1">Show More</a>
<a class="plus" data-article="2">Show More</a>
<a class="plus" data-article="3">Show More</a>

... some more HTML

<div id="div1" class="more">Content</div>
<div id="div2" class="more">Content</div>
<div id="div3" class="more">Content</div>
```

and Javascript:

```
(function($) { 
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.more').hide();
    $('a.plus').click(function(){
       var id = 'div' + $(this).attr('data-article');
       $('div#' + id).slideToggle();
       $(this).toggleClass("minus_icon"); 
       return false;
    });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and good effort but i don't want to add non valid `data-article="1"`

Comment: You can modify Adam's solution slightly - instead of using data-article attributes, give your a tags with class="plus" additional id with numbers corresponding to appropriate divs like this:

<a class="plus" id="plus2">Show More</a>

and then use var id = 'div'+substr($(this).id, 4);

(hope I got params to substr function correct).

Answer (score 0):

Give your divs the same class (like 'div_to_toggle') and then instead of $('#div1'), $('#div2'), ... you can use one selector: $('.div_to_toggle') that will select them all:

```
$('.div_to_toggle').hide();
$('.div_to_toggle').slideToggle();
```

Comment: right now when i click on <a> for one box it opens all boxes. now i'm going to try ur solution

Comment: it's not working . when i click on <a> for one box it opens all boxes.