# Can we have external NoScript file?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

Can we have external NoScript file?

If javascript is not avaialbe i want to hide **+** and **-** from According page.

How to do this if i can't edit html `<head>` i only can add any external css and js file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easy way is to add the +/- from Javascript, rather than sticking them directly in the HTML. That way they won't show up if scripts are disabled.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a suitable class, you can hide the elements by default, then show them if JavaScript is enabled.

e.g.:

In CSS:

```
.plusminus { display: none }

<span class="plusminus">+</span>
```

Then, have a JavaScript file that overrides that CSS.

Comment: my javascript code is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044331/how-to-make-jquery-slidetoggle-effect-for-multiple-div-on-same-page/3044662#3044662